# Getting rid of CRLF for new files in Emacs Windows

Tags: emacs, cygwin, newline

I have tried all of this:

Changing coding system:

```
(prefer-coding-system 'iso-latin-1-unix)
```

Ensuring no translation:

```
(add-untranslated-filesystem "C:")
(add-untranslated-filesystem "D:")
```

Setting multibyte characters to nil:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(desktop-save-mode t)
  '(enable-multibyte-characters nil))
```

None of this work for me.

I use Emacs 22.2.1 with Cygwin.

```
GNU Emacs 22.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7100) of 2008-03-26 on RELEASE
```

Here's how I start my emacs (remember %~dp0 puts the dirname of the executing file with path separator )  :

```
@set PATH=c:\cygwin\bin;%~dp0;%PATH%
@start %~dp0runemacs.exe %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the code in the first rectangle on this site for a lisp solution

http://home.att.net/~Tom.Horsley/sitm-emacs.html

```
(setq inhibit-eol-conversion t)
(progn
  ; Stamp out the obnoxious setting of new files to CR-LF mode by
  ; default on w32 systems. Beacuse the dos-w32 function sets up these
  ; hooks when it is loaded, I need to load it merely so I can stamp out
  ; the hooks (never figured out how to keep it from being loaded in the
  ; first place - sigh....
  (require 'dos-w32)
  (remove-hook 'find-file-not-found-hooks 'find-file-not-found-set-buffer-file-coding-system)
)
```